# GMAIL - no label found in Allmail

Tags: gmail-filters

I'm really bummed! I missed a really important email for a job now that came in...I've been checking my Inbox and Spam just in case on my phone.  I just found out I missed the date and have been disqualified.  I assured them I hadn't received the email.  Desperately I searched and found it in Allmail which was ALL the way down the bottom and can only be seen if you check More >...There the email sat with No Label.  HOW did this happen?? HELP! Perhaps if I can explain they will give me another shot!

Comment: Just to add, "All Mail" isn't shown by default on Gmail Desktop unless you _show_ this "system label" in settings.

Comment: We need more information to find out what's going on here. By default, emails aren't labeled. Why do you believe this message should have had a label? Also, are you using Priority Inbox?

Answer (score 1):

"Allmail" isn't really a label. It is, actually, just a way to see *all* of your mail.<sup>1</sup>

If you archive<sup>2</sup> a message without applying a different label, the only place you'll see it (without searching) is in "Allmail". Check to see if you have any filters with the action "Skip the Inbox". If so, that's likely the culprit. If you're using any sort of third-party tool with your Gmail (like a desktop email client like Thunderbird or an online Gmail enhancement tool like Boomerang) it could also act on messages and possibly remove "Inbox" depending on what you're having it do.

More than likely, though, you simply archived the message without realizing it. It can happen if your search is broader than you anticipated and you didn't pay close enough attention.

For the future, you'll want to create a filter that will fire on the message you're expecting and do something so you will notice it. Applying a label is probably the best way, but you can also mark it important. If you want to get extra fancy, auto-forward it to the email-to-SMS gateway provided by your mobile carrier. Or use IFTTT to have a notification appear on your smartphone.

<sup>1</sup> Excepting "Spam" and "Trash".
<sup>2</sup> "Inbox" is really just a label itself, albeit a special one. "Archive" just removes the "Inbox" label from a message.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! But how the heck do I "archive" an email? I didn't know such feature existed.  So as an example can you tell me how I could've archived it without realizing it? I just want to know so that I doesn't happen again.  THANKS SO MUCH!!!

Comment: And just to clarify..the email was sitting in the ALLMAIL box with no label...does that make sense?

Comment: You've never noticed the "archive" button? I really suggest you have a look at the Gmail support center and familiarize yourself with some of the basic features.

Comment: _" And just to clarify..the email was sitting in the ALLMAIL box with no label...does that make sense?"_ Yes. As I said, that's what happens when you archive a message and don't apply any other labels to it.

Comment: No sir, but will go now! UGH...thank you!

Comment: You mention you are using your "phone". In which case it is much easier to accidentally "archive" an email on the Android Gmail application, as opposed to on the Desktop. The "archive" button is the first option on the Android Apps toolbar, and there is no "confirmation", except for an "undo" notice that appears briefly.